# Get Return Result from Called function in Calling Function

Tags: jquery

I know my Question Title may should weird but i didn't had any good Title. My problem is Actually i've Created 2 function, 1 is Global JS function and 2 is local function calling global function. 
My Global function is:

```
function Validate(id, ErrorMessage) {
    if (ErrorMessage != "") {             
        id.attr("data-original-title", ErrorMessage);
        id.css("border", "1px solid red");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My Second Local function calling Global Function is:

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function () {
    //Calling Global function
    if ($("#TextBoxId").val() != "") {
        var GetResult = return Validate($("#TextBoxId"), "Testing Message");
        //Here i would like to get the result i.e. whether it returned  true or false
        if(GetResult == true) { //Do something }
        else { //Do Somthing else }
    }        
});
```

How to get result from 1st function in 2nd JS function

Comment: Make it `var GetResult = Validate($("#TextBoxId"), "Testing Message");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `var GetResult = return Validate($("#TextBoxId"), "Testing Message");`

To

`var GetResult = Validate($("#TextBoxId"), "Testing Message");`

remove that `return` while calling your function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the **return** keyword while assigning the global function's return to the variable `GetResult` as follows:

```
var GetResult = Validate($("#TextBoxId"), "Testing Message");
```

[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1dsc9saj/)

> The return statement stops the execution of a function and returns a
>   value from that function. So it should only be used to output the current function's data to the caller of the function.

Comment: All the answers are correct... Hope i could have marked them all... Thanks guys by the way

Comment: @Amar You can always upvote multiple answers that helped you.